# Ads playing at full volume when phone is silent

Tags: android, ads

Some users report that advertisments play at [full volume](https://androidforums.com/threads/stopping-ads-from-playing-at-full-volume-when-phone-is-silent.937819/) even when the phone is muted.

Can ads perform a call like this:

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, currentVolume, flags);
```

If so, how can this issue be fixed?